# Easy limit using Ɛ-δ proof

Tags: analysis, functions, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

There is a very simple limit that I can prove using L'Hôpital's rule and other techniques, but I can't really do it using the definition of $\epsilon-\delta$.

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{x} -1}{x} =1
$$

Please help! I've been stuck with this for a few weeks. I've even asked some old teachers of mine, and nobody was able to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

As asked, I'm going to show you how far I got. I'm sure I made mistakes, but like I said, I'm really at a loss with this limit. Thanks.

$$
\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{x} -1}{x} =1\ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ \forall \epsilon  >0\ \ \exists \delta  >0\ \ ||\ \ 0< |x|< \delta \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \left| \frac{e^{x} -1}{x} -1\right| < \epsilon 
$$

$$
\left| \frac{e^{x} -1}{x}\right| -| 1| \leqslant \left| \frac{e^{x} -1}{x} -1\right| < \epsilon \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \left| \frac{e^{x} -1}{x}\right| < \epsilon +1
$$

$$
\frac{\left| e^{x} -1\right|}{| x| } = \left| \frac{e^{x} -1}{x}\right| < \epsilon +1
$$

If $\delta \leqslant 1$ then:

$$
-1< x< 1
$$
$$
e^{-1} < e^{x} < e
$$
$$
e^{-1} -1< e^{x} -1< e-1
$$
$$
-( e-1) < e^{-1} -1< e^{x} -1< e-1
$$
$$
\left| e^{x} -1\right| < e-1
$$

So now:

$$
\frac{\left| e^{x} -1\right| }{| x| } < \frac{e-1}{| x| } < \epsilon +1\ \ \Longrightarrow \ \frac{e-1}{\epsilon +1} < | x| < \delta < 1
$$

As you can see, the last part is a contradiction, so clearly there's something I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your efforts if you have tried.

Comment: Sure, that's fair. I've edited my comment to add my best try so far.

Comment: "$\frac{e-1}{|x|} < \epsilon +1$" Not hardly! All you know about $x$ is that $|x| < 1$. While because you are dividing by it, we have to also throw out $x = 0$, that still leaves $x$ to be as small as you want, meaning that its inverse can be as large as you want.

Comment: If you want to prove $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}x = 1$, then you need to prove it either from the definition of $e^x$ or by already-proven properties of $e^x$ (and they need to specifically be properties of exponentiation with base $e$, not with some arbitrary base). I do not know what definition of $e^x$ you are working from (there are many ways of defining it). But you WILL need to involve that definition.